# Merging master into branch in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, branch, git-merge, rebase

I'm working in a feature branch. Since I've been working with it for a few weeks now, I would like to merge any changes from the master into my branch to ensure there are no conflicts.

I find some aspects of this confusing. I can see a *Rebase 'master' onto*  command. Is this what I need?

Also, I read you can only change a branch that you are working in. As you can see from the image below, I'm currently working in master. Does this command still update my *TruckTemplates* branch?

[image]